# Do most webcams contain ROMs (which could contain malware)?

Tags: webcam, rom

If I use a plug and play webcam, is it likely to contain a ROM (e.g., for drivers)? If so, is it likely to contain a virgin PROM when purchased?

Edit: The reason why I am asking this is because I'm worried about malware stored in the webcam's ROM. I am interested in whether it might be PROM as if it is PROM the webcam could overwrite evidence of the malware and I would be none the wiser.

Comment: It would have to have some sort of ROM to store its firmware on; as to a drivers ROM, possibly, but that depends on the manufacturer and how they configured their PCB.  Logically speaking, and I may very well be wrong, this type of device would likely only have a PROM if its firmware is updateable.

Comment: @JW0914 Can't PROM just be edited once and usually only by changing 1s to 0s so how could the firmware be updated with a write to PROM?

Comment: I think you’re looking for storage exposed as USB Mass Storage or similar. The answer to that is: No and no. But maybe first clarify your question and your intended purpose of said storage.

Comment: @physBa Ah, good point - I mixed up PROM and NVRAM

Comment: You are close to an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/222653). Could you perhaps [edit] your question to indicate what problem you're trying to solve, or what goal you have? *Why* do you want to know if a webcam is likely to contain a ROM? By including that in your question others might suggest other ways to achieve what you want.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I have updated my question

Comment: **This is just foil hat territory**. Why on earth would someone go to the trouble of reprogramming a dashcam just to spy on *you*. They can already track your habits on your phone & any computer you own. Much easier job than trying to figure out how to hack a dashcam in order to hide files on it in such a way you couldn't just see them on the SD Card… which of course gets erased & rewriten every day as space dictates & you would only ever actually plug it into any other device if you had a car crash.

Answer (score 3):

The first thing you have to ask is "what is in it for them?"

Almost every modern device has a microcontroller that handles communication over USB, deals with whatever protocol the hardware itself works in, and converts the data into a format that can be transmitted over USB.

That microcontroller might have 32 or 256KB of flash built in, or it might have an external chip where its program and device info is stored.

Even a completely "dumb" device that already knows USB and packages everything up needs *some* kind of write-once ROM that will contain some kind of USB device descriptor information for the driver you install on your computer to be able to recognise it. That ROM might be written at the factory that made the chip or by the people who made the camera and put it all together.

A nefarious party can do any number of things to hide malware in any number of places. They could briefly imitate a keyboard and essentially "type" arbitrary commands, downloading and executing malware. Or they could impersonate a USB stick and hold the initial malware there. There was even some fatal flaw yeats back on processors that exposed debug interfaces via USB that meant a specially crafted USB stick could completely take over a computer without any indication at all to the user.

The problem is that flaws get patched, malwares get detected and protected against, security holes are found and removed. That means that any hardware with an exploit on it has a life expectancy.

Dubious hardware will quickly get noticed and blacklisted, it will quickly get whatever holes it uses patched, and likely any suspect hardware will quickly be removed from sale.

So if you want to operate for any length of time you need to be selective about who you attack with these kinds of devices. Someone who won't notice what is going on, someone who has something you want and you *know* is going to plug in a device you have infected.

That makes this kind of attack in hardware is expensive, time limited and far less worthwhile than a easier pure software methods via the Internet. They also require a very careful approach to who you target for it to be usable for any length of time.

There were, in the past, attacks on major infrastructure that relied on intimate knowledge of the targets systems and their poor security practices where they [relied on people plugging in infected USB sticks they found in a car park.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stuxnet)

The first question you have to ask is "am I stupid enough to plug USB stick I found in a car park?"  If the answer is "Yes" then you've already lost.

First and foremost you should be wary of the Internet at large before random electronics from reputable retailers. A retailer selling infected devices is risking their entire business, while the Internet is anonymous, fast changing and volatile.

Answer (score 2):

In short, no, USB devices do not have any equivalent to PCI "option ROM" which could carry executable code. They do *describe* themselves to the host (providing the product ID, supported interfaces, etc) but any actual drivers must be obtained externally. Webcams typically use a standard "USB Video Class" interface that doesn't require specific drivers, anyway.

But, of course, it is possible that a malicious USB webcam could act as a *different* USB device – for example, there are USB flash drives that emulate keyboards and send fake Win+R keypresses to run commands as soon as they're connected.

Some products even do this "legitimately", e.g. some printer models are a composite device that provides a USB printer interface *and* a USB CD-ROM interface, the latter containing a Windows setup.exe for the drivers. (HP does this.) And because it's an (emulated) CD, in Windows it'll be subject to the Autoplay feature (autorun.inf), although nowadays this no longer runs anything automatically...but in older Windows versions it used to.

So while USB in general doesn't provide any executable code to the host, a device has several ways to *trick* the host into running something.

Answer (score 1):

Modern plug and play webcams, except with the possible exception of high quality name brand ones, are made as *cheap* as possible.  The manufacturers use the cheapest off the shelf USB and camera chipsets, often combined on one chip.  There would not likely be a PROM you could write to.  Remember programable ROMs are more expensive than those you write once to.